# How to apply an array of functions to a value using list comprehension?

Tags: python, arrays, function

I have an array of functions :

```
functions = [function_a,function_b,square,...,last_function]
```

I would like to get the output of function_a(function_b(square(...(last_function("hello"))..))) in a variable in one line, replacing the dots by a list comprehension trick.

Like this :

```
tmp = input
for f in functions:
  tmp = f(tmp)
output = tmp
```

Without using tmp, in one line.

Comment: Does `reduce(lambda x, y: x(y), [functions, ...])` work? Just a guess

Comment: By the way the code you have does `last_fuction(...(square(function_b(function_a("hello")))))`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm aware of that, but order doesn't matter in my question.

Comment: A list comprehension creates a list; you actually want to reduce a list to a single value, which is what `reduce` does (`functools.reduce` in Python 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
your_value = 3
result = reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), function_list, your_value)
```

For example:

```
>>> functions = [lambda x: x + 2, lambda x: x * 2]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), functions, 1)
6
```